# Cordova build error- Android

Tags: android, cordova

I was trying to build my android app. Following error occurs every time.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\INTEL\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The following error occurre
d while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 5 seconds

C:\SocialNoiseApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "ant debug -f C:\SocialNoiseApp\p
latforms\android\build.xml -Dout.dir=ant-build -Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: C:\SocialNoiseApp\platforms\android\
cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: C:\SocialNoiseApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed wit
h exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
```

My Environment variable have following path:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\ant\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%/tools;%ANDROID_HOME%/tools;%ANDROID_HOME%/platform-tools
```

Comment: try writing this three line in the CMD 

android,
ant,
javac,
and see i any of them is not working

Comment: find check_reqs.bat somewhere in %userprofile%\.cordova and run it, it should show you more details. And how are you building?

Answer (score 0):

Clean your android project using eclipse or ant
Then build your cordova project. Hope this will work for you..